# Accessing OfficeRuntime.storage within an dialog in Office JS Excel-Add-In

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I'm creating an Office JS Excel Add-In using React & TypeScript.

There is a dialog I open from task pane (Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync) or custom functions runtime (OfficeRuntime.displayWebDialog) and this dialog has an input which's data should be stored inside the OfficeRuntime.storage to be available for task pane and custom functions runtime as well.

I at first tried to directly write into the storage from the dialog itself and this worked fine while running the add-in in Excel online. But when I try to run it in Excel desktop accessing the storage doesn't work.

So i now changed the behavior and read from the store before opening the dialog and set it via request get parameter (what find kind of ugly myself) and return the value via Office.context.ui.messageParent.

I only get the following error

"name":"Internal Error",
"message":"An internal error has occurred.",
"code":5001

In this article MS teaches about such a scenario and it seems they propose to access the storage from custom functions and task pan instead of the dialog. But since it works in Office online (yes I'm aware of the different run time environments) and the exception doesn't tell any useful information I'm not convinced that's how it should behave yet.

Is further investigation useful or is this functionality in the given context just not available?

thx for your time!

Comment: Since this sounds like a bug (or at minimum a design limitation), I recommend you post it as an issue on https://github.com/officedev/office-js/issues, where someone from the product team can go help investigate.

Comment: Where do you get the error message? is it from messageParent or displayDialog? I assume it is not from localStorage. It will be helpful if you can provide the parameter when you are calling these api.

Comment: The error is from calling OfficeRuntime.storage.getItem(...), at the moment I'm not able to reproduce it for dialogs opened from custom functions desktop, but I get the following error executing this line in dialog opened from task pane:
{"name":"Permission Denied","message":"You don't have sufficient permissions for this action.","code":7000}

Comment: BTW here is the link to the GitHub issue for any interested reader. It contains some additional information https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/653